# jquery use .stopPropagation() on hover menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stoppropagation

How to use event .stopPropagation() (or something else) in the following situation.
I have a standard menu with submenu. In the submenu background, I have background image which I need to overlay adding pseuso-element (background:green) on the parent. Because with jquery I cant control css pseudo-elements (I need control opacity), I add another class to my parent.
Everything works as I need, but adding / removing the class on parent makes the image background blink.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caesarSK/to2bno20/1/)

[my site live (top menu is my problem)](http://sodanca.sk)

```
HTML:
<ul class="top-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <div class="submenu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sublink 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sublink 5</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
            $(".submenu a").mouseover(function(e){
              $(".submenu").addClass("myclass");
            }).mouseout(function(e){
              var cover = $(".submenu");
              cover.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
                    cover.removeClass("myclass");
                }, 2000)
              );
              e.stopPropagation();
            });
```

css

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul.top-menu {
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
}
ul.top-menu li a {
  color:black;
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}
.submenu {
  position:absolute;
  background:red url("http://www.metalclays.com/content/images/thumbs/0002871_texture-tile-fireworks_100.jpeg");
  background-position:right top;
  background-size:200px auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  z-index:0;
}
.submenu:after {
  content:"";
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-1;
}  
.submenu.myclass:after {
  opacity:1;
}
.submenu ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.submenu a {
  color:white;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
$(".submenu a").mouseover(function(e){
  $(".submenu").addClass("myclass");
}).mouseout(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".submenu").removeClass("myclass");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> but adding / removing the class on parent makes the image background blink

This happens because on **mouseover** you add and add the class. Change from:

```
$(".submenu a").mouseover(function(e){
    $(".submenu").addClass("myclass");
})
```

to:

```
$(".submenu a").mouseover(function(e){
    if ($(".submenu.myclass").length == 0) {
        $(".submenu").addClass("myclass");
    }
})
```

The [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to2bno20/3/).